# how to check duplicate records in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$queryb = "SELECT product, imei, country, warranty, config from PRODUCT WHERE product_slno = '$mnserialno' ";
$resultb = mysql_query($queryb, $gndbconn) ;
if(mysql_num_rows($resultb) > 0)
{
    $queryc = "UPDATE PRODUCT SET product='$desc', product_slno='$mnserialno',imei='$imei',country='$country',warranty='$warranty',config='$config' WHERE product_slno = '.$mnserialno.' ";
     $resutc = mysql_query($queryc, $gndbconn) ;
 }
else{
    $querya  = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT SET product='$desc', product_slno='$mnserialno',imei='$imei',country='$country',warranty='$warranty',config='$config'";
    $resulta = mysql_query($querya, $gndbconn) ; 
 }
```

I want to check the serial number if that serial number already exist in database so records get update, otherwise it get insert into the database.
but the code inserting the records only, no updation, what is the fault i am not getting,
how to prevent the duplicate entry?

Comment: **STOP** using depricated `mysql_*`API. use `mysqli_`  API or `PDO` with prepared statement

Comment: Just use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: do u say always if fails? echo mysql_num_rows($resultb) for the record that exist

Comment: use `$resutc = mysql_query($queryc, $gndbconn) or die(mysql_error($gndbconn)) ;` to see the sql error

Comment: yes it fails, and in place of updation its inserting data?

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($resultb) > 0) change it to if(mysql_num_rows($resultb) > 1)

Comment: $resultb = mysql_query($queryb, $gndbconn); print_r($resultb);
$num=mysql_num_rows($resultb); echo $num; and post the result for the record that exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT SET
    (`product`, `product_slno`, `imei`, `country`, `warranty`, `config`)
VALUES
    ('" . $desc . "',  '" . $mnserialno . "', '" . $imei . "', '" . $country . "', '" . $warranty . "', '" . $config . "')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    product='" . $desc . "',
    product_slno='" . $mnserialno . "',
    imei='" . $imei . "',
    country='" . $country . "',
    warranty='" . $warranty . "',
    config='" . $config . "'";
```